# how to force users to edit just their own record of model in django admin panel

Tags: django, user-permissions

I want to force users to edit just their own record of the model in the Django admin panel with permissions. For example: they can just see their comments and edit them only or their posts as well, I want to use Django admin panel only and I don't want to create A separate panel what should I do?

Comment: I would say allowing users to use admin panel is asking for trouble anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think you can do that or it would get really complicated and some users might find ways to exploit. The simplest way is creating a form with post request, Tell me in comments if you want an example!